# 2 psu conected as split + and -

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have 2 pcs 24VDC 3Amp ITE adaptor and i want to make split supply for 24v +/-
1 of the adaptor i remove the earth wire on the wall plug 3 pin and 1 is connected with earth.Adaptor A conected with Earth and adaptor B without Earth connection.I put diode on both adaptor + and - output.
I have try this and the adaptor accept the conection.But i test it just for 1 minute.Im wondering if this connection is safe and can be use on long period.
If i remove earth wire on both A and B adaptor,the 24VDC out absolute deadly :)So only 1 adaptor is connect with earth.Can i use this connection for split supply?The adaptor is same brand.Should i add anything for this connection?Im noob lol.
Sorry my english it's terrible.
[image]

Comment: What are the parallel diodes for?

Answer (score 1):

Laboratory power supplies' OUTPUTS are floating respect to earth ground. They can do this because they are isolated (have a transformer inside). Anyway, their CASES are always connected to earth ground so you don't get electrocuted when you touch/operate them.

If your supplies are isolated, then it is ok to disconnect their **outputs** from earth ground... but please *keep the earth pin in the plug so the cases/chasis of the supplies are kept at a safe voltage*. To do this **you have to check first that they are isolated** (which is usually the case for PC supplies and voltage adapters).

Comment: It is *not* safe to disconnect the secondary GND from PE (protective earth). You will no longer be protected against isolation fault!

Comment: @TurboJ then how do laboratory supplies provide floating voltage output with respect to ground?

Comment: Correction: It is not safe to disconnect PE in *PC (ATX) power supplies* and similar devices. There are better isolated power supplies that don't require PE.

Comment: We agree on that it is a good idea to keep the PE pin in the plug, as written in the answer. The question is, if this PE point is connected to any of the OUTPUT voltages of the supply (not the chasis).